# Carrierwave image extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, upload, carrierwave

I'm trying to determine whether a remote url is an image.  Most url's have .jpg, .png etc...but some images, like google images, have no extension...i.e.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbK2NSUILnFozlX-oCWQ0r2PS2gHPPF7c8XaxGuJFGe83KGJkhFtlLXU_u

I've tried using FastImage to determine whether a url is an image.  It works when any URL is fed into it...

How could I ensure that remote urls use FastImage and uploaded files use the whitelist?  Here is what have in my uploader.  Avatar_remote_url isn't recognized...what do I do in the uploader to just test remote urls and not regular files.

```
  def extension_white_list
    if defined? avatar_remote_url && !FastImage.type(CGI::unescape(avatar_remote_url)).nil?
      # ok to process
    else # regular uploaded file should detect the following extensions
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
  end
```

Comment: It might be possible to use regex to allow anything from http://encrpyted-tbn0.gstatic to be uploaded

Answer (score 3):

if all you have to work with is a url like that you can send a HEAD request to the server to obtain the content type for the image. From that you can obtain the extension

```
require 'net/http'
require 'mime/types'

def get_extension(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
  request = Net::HTTP::Head.new(uri.request_uri)
  response = http.request(request)
  content_type = response['Content-Type']
  MIME::Types[content_type].first.extensions.first
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with the code you provided and some of the code provided in the [CarrierWave Wiki for validating remote URLs](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Validate-the-URL-for-remote-uploads).

You can create a new validator in `lib/remote_image_validator.rb`.

```
require 'fastimage'

class RemoteImageValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    raise(ArgumentError, "A regular expression must be supplied as the :format option of the options hash") unless options[:format].nil? || options[:format].is_a?(Regexp)
    configuration = { :message => "is invalid or not responding", :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)) }
    configuration.update(options)

    if value =~ configuration[:format]
      begin
        if FastImage.type(CGI::unescape(avatar_remote_url))
          true
        else
          object.errors.add(attribute, configuration[:message]) and false
        end
      rescue
        object.errors.add(attribute, configuration[:message]) and false
      end
    else
      object.errors.add(attribute, configuration[:message]) and false
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :avatar_remote_url,
    :remote_image => { 
      :format => /(^$)|(^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$)/ix,
      :unless => remote_avatar_url.blank?
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue where creating the different versions from the original was failing because ImageMagick could not figure out the correct encoder to use due to the missing extension. Here is a monkey-patch I applied in Rails that fixed my problem:

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Download
      class RemoteFile
        def original_filename
          value = File.basename(file.base_uri.path)
          mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup(file.content_type)
          unless File.extname(value).present? || mime_type.blank?
            value = "#{value}.#{mime_type.symbol}"
          end
          value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I believe this will address the problem you are having as well since it ensures the existence of a file extension when the content type is set appropriately.

UPDATE:

The master branch of carrierwave has a different solution to this problem that uses the `Content-Disposition` header to figure out the filename. Here is the relevant pull request on [github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1056).

Comment: This is awesome! Why didn't you do a pull request to Carrierwave, This is obviously a better approach now in modern times with image servers and everything...

Comment: I was actually in the process of submitting one @NielsKristian :-D

Comment: I think it will be welcomed https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1247 :-)

Comment: I've created the pull request [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1248)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I've merged the PR by @Hamed. Thanks!